# make image transparent(without background)

Tags: javascript

I want to remove  background from this example
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bNfr.jpg)

So,is there any possibility to make this image without background(transparent) using javascript or any librirary js ?

Comment: Does this answer to your question? https://michael-holstein.medium.com/remove-background-from-person-by-using-ai-and-javascript-eb85674f9e8d

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use it but the result is not perfectly what I want.
you can see
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRUsz.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The image's format is `.jpg`. There is no simple way making background of `.jpg` image transparent using only JS. But as Ahmad Faraz already commented there is some JS libraries that can do this for you.

Instead: some simple way of going around the problem:

1. You might use graphic editing programs to have a `.jpg` image cut
   and transformed to transparent background.
2. You should use images with transparent background already.